# WHERE clause with difference between two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

A rather simple issue but having some problems with it.

```
SELECT updated_date, date_time, updated_date-date_time AS diff 
FROM rainfall 
WHERE diff > '00:05:44'
```

would return me

> ERROR: column "diff" does not exist

I still would like to perform the where clause operation on the new diff column. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

**EDIT**: thanks for replying everyone.

I actually would like to query

```
SELECT 
    station_id, date_time, 
    LAG(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY date_time),
    date_time-LAG(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY date_time) AS lagdiff 
FROM 
    waterlevel
WHERE 
    date_data BETWEEN '2021-01-29 00:00:00' AND '2021-01-30 00:00:00'
    AND date_time-LAG(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY date_time) > '00:05:00'
```

Unfortunately, this returns

> ERROR: window functions are not allowed in WHERE

So, I would either have to use the alias, or fix the window functions not allowed in where issue which is admittingly much harder LOL.

But I would still appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Replace `diff` in the WHERE clause with the expression `updated_date-date_time`.

Comment: you can not use alias in where clause

Comment: Shouldn't it be Difference? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140298/how-to-find-difference-between-two-columns-data
Check this for reference

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use alias in where clause

```
 SELECT updated_date,date_time,updated_date-date_time as diff
 FROM rainfall WHERE updated_date-date_time > '00:05:44'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's cool guys, I should use a CTE. Thanks guys

```
WITH mycte AS(
SELECT station_id,date_time,LAG(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY date_time),
date_time-LAG(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY date_time) as lagdiff 
FROM waterlevel
WHERE date_data BETWEEN '2021-01-29 00:00:00' AND '2021-01-30 00:00:00'
)
SELECT * FROM mycte WHERE lagdiff>'00:15:00'
```